# How to add another parallel AJAX call to the promises chain

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function, promise

I'm writing an app which

1. makes an AJAX call to establish user location based on an IP
   address, then
2. makes a second AJAX call to provide current weather data
   for this location, then
3. shows this data in DOM

I've developed the following promises chain which successfully delivers the above:

```
getUserLocation()
  .then(function(locationData) {
    return getCurrentWeather(locationData);
  }).then(function(currentWeatherData) {
    return showCurrentWeather(currentWeatherData);
  });
```

Now I need to add a further functionality to the app so that it:

1. makes an AJAX call to establish user location based on an IP
   address, then
2. makes a second AJAX call to provide current weather data
   for this location, **and
   makes a third (concurrent, parallel) AJAX call to provide weather forecast data for this location, then**
3. shows the current weather data in DOM, **and
   shows the weather forecast data in DOM**

Below is what I've been experimenting with, but it does not work. Would you know how to fix this? My objective is to find a solution that makes only one AJAX call to get user location and then uses this data in two further AJAX calls (returned from the `getCurrentWeather` and `getWeatherForecast` functions).

```
getUserLocation()
  .then(function(locationData) {
    getCurrentWeather(locationData);
    getWeatherForecast(locationData);
  }).then(function() {
    showCurrentWeather(currentWeatherData);
    showWeatherForecast(weatherForecastData);
  });
```

**UPDATE 1 - WORKING SOLUTION FOUND:**

Thanks to the approach suggested by @ReedSpool, I've managed to develop a working code:

```
getUserLocation()
  .then(function(locationData) {
    return jQuery.when(
      getCurrentWeather(locationData),
      getWeatherForecast(locationData)
    );
  }).then(function(currentWeatherData, weatherForecastData) {
    showCurrentWeather(currentWeatherData[0]);
    showWeatherForecast(weatherForecastData[0]);
  });
```

The solution includes the `jQuery.when`. I also had to add index values of `0` to the arguments passed to the `showCurrentWeather` and `showWeatherForecast` functions. This is because the returned JSON now includes additional information about the `readyState` and `status`. This was not happening with my initial scenario with only one AJAX call to the weather API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're indeed using jQuery promises (I'm gathering from the tags on your question, since the code provided has no jQuery specific stuff), then you're looking for `jQuery.when()` Every complete promise library has a similar function to this (Q.all for example)

Notice in your first example, you return the result of `getCurrentWeather(locationData)`. Returning a promise inside a promise callback makes the outer promise wait for the inner promise to resolve. To wait for two or more promises to resolve, use `jQuery.when()` like...

```
getUserLocation()
  .then(function(locationData) {
    return jQuery.when(
      getCurrentWeather(locationData),
      getWeatherForecast(locationData)
    );
  }).then(function(curretnWeatherData, weatherForecastData) {
    showCurrentWeather(curretnWeatherData[0]);
    showWeatherForecast(weatherForecastData[0]);
  });
```

See the documentation here: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Comment: Thank you, the `getCurrentWeather` and `getCurrentWeather` successfully deliver the AJAX calls. However  now the `showCurrentWeather` and `showWeatherForecast` functions receive some wrong data. After stringifying it I can see: `[{"readyState":1},{"readyState":1}]` object. Would you know what may be causing this?

Comment: @PiotrBerebecki Not sure. Could you expand on the implementation of `getCurrentWeather` and `getWeatherForecast` in your question? Specifically, do they return the result of `$.ajax` directly? You might have to do `currentWeatherData.data` or something (even tho your stringification doesn't quite show that)

Comment: @PiotrBerebecki The documentation makes me think the `a` in `$.ajax(...).then(function (a) {})` is an array whose first value is the data you want, but the stringification you show doesn't support that, so I'm not sure

Comment: Thanks to your excellent solution I've managed to develop a working code. Please see Update 1 in my question. Please update your code so that I can accept  it as an answer.  The problems were the square brackets, and the need for the index values in the arguments passed to the functions showing the weather.

Comment: @PiotrBerebecki Glad it helped, sorry about the syntax confusion! Updated. Cheers :-D